# React Component with different parts in different locations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Current I have a React component which have 2 parts, they are tightly coupled together.

The problem is I need these 2 parts display in different location for different pages.

Please see the below wireframe for illustration.
[image]

My approach currently is splitting the component's part into 2 separated components and there are event handling code between them which i need to copy and paste to every page that contains these parts.
Is there a better way to structure these parts as a single component to void code duplication of even handling and allow flexibility to place them in any location we want within a page.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using functional components or class components? The answer to that will influence which options are available for code sharing.

Comment: @NicholasTower i use functional component at the moment, but if class component can solve it, i wont mind to convert it

Comment: no no, function component makes it much easier. I'll type up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works to have a single copy of the control code (eg, if you just want a single state that's shared between all pages, with each page being able to alter the behavior of other pages), you could put the logic in a component near the top of the component tree, where it's a common ancestor to all pages. It can then use context to make any values available to the pages.

```
const ExampleContext = React.createContext();

const ExampleProvider = () => {
  // Put all your event handling code that you've been copy/pasting here.

  // Any data that needs to be available to part1 and part 2, put here.
  // Memoization is needed if you're creating an object or array; you can
  // skip it if you only need to provide a single primitive.
  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      someValue,
      someFunction,
      etc
    }
  }, [/* dependencies */]);

  return (
    <ExampleContext.Provider value={value}>
      {/* these pages can be farther down the tree; they just need to be descendants of ExampleContext.Provider */}
      <Page1/>
      <Page2/>
    </ExampleContext.Provider>
  )
}

// Then consume the context like this:

const Page1 = () => {
  const value = useContext(ExampleContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <Part1 /* whatever props are needed from value *//>
      <Component1/>
      <Part2 /* whatever props are needed from value *//>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If each page needs to be independant of the others (have their own state and event listeners), then instead of copy pasting the code, you can extract the logic into a custom hook for easy reuse:

```
const useExample = () => {
  // put all your event handling code that you've been copy/pasting here

  // return any values that will be needed by Part1 and Part2
  return {
    someValue,
    someFunction,
    etc
  }
}

// Used like:
const Page1 = () => {
  const value = useExample();
  return (
    <div>
      <Part1 /* whatever props are needed from value *//>
      <Component1/>
      <Part2 /* whatever props are needed from value *//>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: In my current setup, i have react-router mapping with all pages declared on the same file. This could be an approach, but what i worry is i will need to keep this context all the time, even i only use it for few specific pages. Is this going to affect performance of whole application?

Comment: You'll want to memoize the context value like i showed, so that context consumers don't need to rerender unless something changes. And you should probably also use React.memo on whatever component comes directly below the Provider, so that it doesn't need to render unless a prop changes. Do those two things, and you should be good for performance. Of course, if you write some really gnarly code you could prove me wrong, but i'm gonna put that one on you :)

Comment: cool, memoization makes a lot of sense here. Thanks a lot